# If $y\sim u(x,1)$, what's the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I am thinking about when a function $f(y)=y$, and $y$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(x,1)$, what will the derivative $\frac{df}{dx}$ be like?

Comment: So f is the identity function.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Hi, it can be any other function that doesn't directly depend on x, but y's distribution is determined by x, so I'm confused, when x gets larger, the probability of y being larger is increased, should the derivative of f(y) still be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the random variable $y$ has a *distribution* that is a function of $x$, but the function $f$ is not a function of $x$, so:

$$\frac{df}{dx}(y) = 0.$$

(Note that if you were to write a probability statement about $f(y)$ then that *probability statement* would be a function of $x$ and you would then get a non-trivial answer.)